# useEffect - Prevent infinite loop when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I'd like the user to be able to sort a list of todo items. When the users selects an item from a dropdown it will set the `sortKey` which will create a new version of `setSortedTodos`, and in turn trigger the `useEffect` and call `setSortedTodos`.

The below example works exactly how I want, however eslint is prompting me to add `todos` to the `useEffect` dependancy array, and if I do it causes an infinite loop (as you would expect).

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState('title');

const setSortedTodos = useCallback((data) => {
  const cloned = data.slice(0);

  const sorted = cloned.sort((a, b) => {
    const v1 = a[sortKey].toLowerCase();
    const v2 = b[sortKey].toLowerCase();

    if (v1 < v2) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (v1 > v2) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  setTodos(sorted);
}, [sortKey]);

useEffect(() => {
    setSortedTodos(todos);
}, [setSortedTodos]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useCallback, useEffect} = React;

const exampleToDos = [
    {title: "This", priority: "1 - high", text: "Do this"},
    {title: "That", priority: "1 - high", text: "Do that"},
    {title: "The Other", priority: "2 - medium", text: "Do the other"},
];

function Example() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(exampleToDos);
    const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState('title');

    const setSortedTodos = useCallback((data) => {
      const cloned = data.slice(0);

      const sorted = cloned.sort((a, b) => {
        const v1 = a[sortKey].toLowerCase();
        const v2 = b[sortKey].toLowerCase();

        if (v1 < v2) {
          return -1;
        }

        if (v1 > v2) {
          return 1;
        }

        return 0;
      });

      setTodos(sorted);
    }, [sortKey]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSortedTodos(todos);
    }, [setSortedTodos]);

    const sortByChange = useCallback(e => {
        setSortKey(e.target.value);
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            Sort by:&nbsp;
            <select onChange={sortByChange}>
                <option selected={sortKey === "title"} value="title">Title</option>
                <option selected={sortKey === "priority"} value="priority">Priority</option>
            </select>
            {todos.map(({text, title, priority}) => (
                <div className="todo">
                    <h4>{title} <span className="priority">{priority}</span></h4>
                    <div>{text}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.todo {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 4px;
}
.todo h4 {
    margin: 2px;
}
.priority {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm thinking there has to be a better way of doing this that keeps eslint happy.

Comment: Just a side note: The `sort` callback can be just: `return a[sortKey].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[sortKey].toLowerCase());` which also has the advantage of doing a locale compare if the environment has reasonable locale information. If you like, you can throw destructuring at it, too: https://pastebin.com/7X4M1XTH

Comment: What error is `eslint` throwing?

Comment: Could you update the question to provide a runnable [mcve] of the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button)? Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That way people can check that their proposed solutions don't have the infinite loop problem...

Comment: That's a really interesting approach, and a really interesting problem. As you say, you can understand why ESLint thinks you need to add `todos` to the dependency array on `useEffect`, and you can see why you shouldn't. :-)

Comment: I added the live example for you. Really want to see this answered.

Comment: The eslint error is `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'todos'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd argue that this means that going about it this way is not ideal. The function is indeed dependent on `todos`. If `setTodos` is called somewhere else, the callback function has to be recomputed, otherwise it operates on stale data.

Why do you store the sorted array in state anyway? You can use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to sort the values when either the key or the array changes:

```
const sortedTodos = useMemo(() => {
  return Array.from(todos).sort((a, b) => {
    const v1 = a[sortKey].toLowerCase();
    const v2 = b[sortKey].toLowerCase();

    if (v1 < v2) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (v1 > v2) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });
}, [sortKey, todos]);
```

Then reference `sortedTodos` everywhere.

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useCallback, useMemo} = React;

const exampleToDos = [
    {title: "This", priority: "1 - high", text: "Do this"},
    {title: "That", priority: "1 - high", text: "Do that"},
    {title: "The Other", priority: "2 - medium", text: "Do the other"},
];

function Example() {
    const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState('title');
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(exampleToDos);

    const sortedTodos = useMemo(() => {
      return Array.from(todos).sort((a, b) => {
        const v1 = a[sortKey].toLowerCase();
        const v2 = b[sortKey].toLowerCase();

        if (v1 < v2) {
          return -1;
        }

        if (v1 > v2) {
          return 1;
        }

        return 0;
      });
    }, [sortKey, todos]);

    const sortByChange = useCallback(e => {
        setSortKey(e.target.value);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            Sort by:&nbsp;
            <select onChange={sortByChange}>
                <option selected={sortKey === "title"} value="title">Title</option>
                <option selected={sortKey === "priority"} value="priority">Priority</option>
            </select>
            {sortedTodos.map(({text, title, priority}) => (
                <div className="todo">
                    <h4>{title} <span className="priority">{priority}</span></h4>
                    <div>{text}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.todo {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 4px;
}
.todo h4 {
    margin: 2px;
}
.priority {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

There is no need to store the sorted values in state, since you can always derive/compute the sorted array from the "base" array and the sort key. I'd argue it also makes your code easier to understand since it is less complex.

Comment: Oh nice use of `useMemo`. Just a side-question, why not use `.localCompare` in the  sort?

Comment: That would indeed be better. I just copied the OP's code and didn't pay attention to that (not really relevant to the problem).

Comment: Really simple, easy to understand solution.

Comment: Ah yes, useMemo! Forgot about that :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the infinite loop is because todos doesn't match the previous reference and the effect will rerun.

Why use an effect for a click-action anyway?
Your can run it in a function like so:

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

function sortTodos(e) {
    const sortKey = e.target.value;
    const clonedTodos = [...todos];
    const sorted = clonedTodos.sort((a, b) => {
        return a[sortKey.toLowerCase()].localeCompare(b[sortKey.toLowerCase()]);
    });

    setTodos(sorted);
}
```

and on your dropdown do an `onChange`.

```
    <select onChange="sortTodos"> ......
```

Note on the dependency by the way, ESLint is right!
Your Todos, in the case described above, are a dependency and should be in the list.
The approach on the selection of an item is wrong, and hence your problem.

Comment: *"sort will return a new instance of an array"* Not the built-in sort method. It sorts the array in-place. `data.slice(0)` creates the copy.

Comment: That is not true when you do a `setState` since it will not edit the existing object and therefor will clone it internally. Wrong wording in my answer, true. I'll edit this.

Comment: `setState` does not clone data. Why do you think that?

Comment: @Tikkes - No, `setState` doesn't clone anything. Felix and the OP are correct, you need to copy the array before sorting it.

Comment: Okay yes, sorry. I need some more reading on internals it seems. You indeed have to copy and not change the existing `state`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is to use functional form of `setState`:

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(exampleToDos);
    const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState('title');

    const setSortedTodos = useCallback((data) => {

      setTodos(currTodos => {
        return currTodos.sort((a, b) => {
          const v1 = a[sortKey].toLowerCase();
          const v2 = b[sortKey].toLowerCase();

          if (v1 < v2) {
            return -1;
          }

          if (v1 > v2) {
            return 1;
          }

          return 0;
        });
      })

    }, [sortKey]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSortedTodos(todos);
    }, [setSortedTodos, todos]);
```

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-2on9p)

Even if you're copying the state in order to not mutate the original one, it's still not guaranteed that you'll get its latest value, due to setting state being async. Plus most of the methods will return a shallow copy, so you might end up mutating the original state anyways.

Using functional `setState` ensures that you get the latest value of the state and do not mutate the original state value.

Comment: *"and do not mutate the original state value."* I don't think React passes a *copy* to the callback. `.sort` changes the array in-place, so you'd still have to copy it yourself.

Comment: Hmm, good point, I actually can't find any confirmation that it passes the copy of the state, altho I remember reading smth like that earlier.

Comment: Found it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often. 'we can use the functional update form of setState. It lets us specify how the state needs to change *without referencing the current state*'

Comment: I don't read that as getting a copy. It just means that you don't have to provide the current state as "external" dependency.